# Projection of array elements using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following json document:

```
{
    "Section": {
        "Name": "Section 1",
        "Description": "Section 1 information",
        "Icon": "test.png"
    },
    "Data": [{
        "Name": "Firstname",
        "Desc": "Users first name",
        "Type": "Text"
    }, {
        "Name": "Lastname",
        "Desc": "Users last name",
        "Type": "Text"
    }]
} {
    "Section": {
        "Name": "Section 2",
        "Description": "Section 2 information",
        "Icon": "test.png"
    },
    "Data": [{
        "Name": "Section 2 Item",
        "Desc": "Section 2 Desc",
        "Type": "Text"
    }]
}
```

I wanted to ask if there is any way to project items based on Data.Name. Like project everything with Data.Name in ['Firstname', 'Section 2 Item'] including the Section object. So the result should be:

```
{
    "Section": {
        "Name": "Section 1",
        "Description": "Section 1 information",
        "Icon": "test.png"
    },
    "Data": [{
        "Name": "Firstname",
        "Desc": "Users first name",
        "Type": "Text"
    }]
} {
    "Section": {
        "Name": "Section 2",
        "Description": "Section 2 information",
        "Icon": "test.png"
    },
    "Data": [{
        "Name": "Section 2 Item",
        "Desc": "Section 2 Desc",
        "Type": "Text"
    }]
}
```

Not sure if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `$` positional projection operator which identifies the index of the array element matched in the query object:

```
db.test.find(
    {'Data.Name': {$in: ["Firstname", "Section 2 Item"]}}, 
    {Section: 1, 'Data.$': 1})
```

Comment: I m sure I tried that before I posted my question. In any case it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot.